# Leaflet - Customer Tile Cache Scheme Review, Munich

Tags: leaflet, tiles, cache

I am interested in user-specific tiling schemes and serverless display with Leaflet. I have come across problems that I cannot solve on my own.

There are older requests in the forum for the display of user-specific tile schemes with Leaflet. I took up the example from the thread  [SAS Planet cached tiles for use in Leaflet map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341108/sas-planet-cached-tiles-for-use-in-leaflet-map) and tried to reproduce the example. I encountered the problem that tiles deeper than zoom level 19 cannot be displayed.

I used the following JS code to display the tile bundle from the cache:

```
    L.TileLayer.customTiles = L.TileLayer.extend({
    getTileUrl: function (tile_bundle) {
            x = tile_bundle.x + 0,
            y = tile_bundle.y + 0,
            z0 = tile_bundle.z + 1,
            x0 = Math.floor(tile_bundle.x / 1024) + 0,
            x1 = Math.floor(tile_bundle.x % 1024) + 0,
            y0 = Math.floor(tile_bundle.y / 1024),
            y1 = Math.floor(tile_bundle.y % 1024);
        const tile_view = `./gMapCache/z${z0}/${x0}/x${x}/${y0}/y${y}.jpg`;
        console.log('tile_bundle', z0,x0,x,y0,y,x1,y1, tile_view);
        return tile_view; 
        },
});
L.tileLayer.customTiles = function (tile_bundle) { return new L.TileLayer.customTiles({maxZoom: 22}).addTo(map) }; var Ausgabekarte = L.tileLayer.customTiles({}).addTo(map);
```

The algorithm for calculating the path to the tiles should be correct. However, the tiles from the directory from gMapCache/z19 and below are not displayed. Does anyone know a solution for this?

Whether the tile is actually present should be displayed in a new browser window with a click of the mouse:

```
    map.on('click', function(click) 
    {
    clickzoom = map.getZoom();
    var latlng = map.mouseEventToLatLng(click.originalEvent);
    var layerPoint = map.latLngToContainerPoint(latlng);
            x = layerPoint.x + 0,
            y = layerPoint.y + 0,
            z0 = clickzoom + 0,
            x0 = Math.floor(x / 1024) + 0,
            x1 = Math.floor(x % 1024) + 0,
            y0 = Math.floor(y / 1024),
            y1 = Math.floor(y % 1024);
    var tile_on_click = `./gMapCache/z${z0}/${x0}/x${x}/${y0}/y${y}.jpg`;
    var clickurl = ["<br><a href=\"" + tile_grid_dir + "\"></a>"];

    console.log( layerPoint, x,y,'on click: ', tile_on_click);

    alert(
        "\rCLICK.TELEMETRIC URL to Tile:\r\r" +
        "URL: " + clickurl + "\n" + 
        "\n\n" )
    });
```

The attached ZIP Conatiner contains an example dataset. [ZIP with dataset example](https://www.namotec.de/asku/2024.leaflet%20customer%20tile%20cache%20scheme%20review,%20munich.tar.7z). The same example online: [LiveView](https://namotec.de/asku/2024.leaflet%20customer%20tile%20cache%20scheme%20review,%20munich/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No matter what I tried and where I specified `maxZoom` option, when custom layer was created it had `maxZoom` option set to 18.

The only working solution seems to be to use `L.setOptions` method to set `maxZoom` option for created layer immediately after creation and before it's added to the map.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
L.TileLayer.CustomTiles = L.TileLayer.extend({
  getTileUrl: function (tile_bundle) {
    x = tile_bundle.x + 0,
    y = tile_bundle.y + 0,
    z0 = tile_bundle.z + 1,
    x0 = Math.floor(tile_bundle.x / 1024) + 0,
    x1 = Math.floor(tile_bundle.x % 1024) + 0,
    y0 = Math.floor(tile_bundle.y / 1024),
    y1 = Math.floor(tile_bundle.y % 1024);
    const tile_view = `./gMapCache/z${z0}/${x0}/x${x}/${y0}/y${y}.jpg`;
    return tile_view; 
  }
});

L.tileLayer.customTiles = function () {
  var layer = new L.TileLayer.CustomTiles();
  L.setOptions(layer, {maxZoom: 24});
  return layer;
};
var Ausgabekarte = L.tileLayer.customTiles();
Ausgabekarte.addTo(map);
```

Comment: The workaround to set the L.setOptions to overwrite the default maxZoom works for me. Thx

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, here is the complete code
([LiveViewWorkaround](https://namotec.de/asku/2024.leaflet%20customer%20tile%20cache%20scheme%20review,%20munich/full_code.html)).
I will soon deactivate the external links contained above.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = L.map('map',{zoomDelta: 500, zoomSnap: 1, wheelPxPerZoomLevel: 100, minZoom: 0, maxZoom: 20, maxNativeZoom: 18}).setView([48.138535154457244, 11.57369971275329],18);


// local custom gMapCache:
// https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341108/sas-planet-cached-tiles-for-use-in-leaflet-map
L.TileLayer.customTiles = L.TileLayer.extend({ getTileUrl: function (tile_bundle) 
    {
    // localhost Tile-Schema short:
    const kachel = `./gMapCache/z${tile_bundle.z + 1}/${Math.floor(tile_bundle.x / 1024)}/x${tile_bundle.x}/${Math.floor(tile_bundle.y / 1024)}/y${tile_bundle.y}.jpg`; 
    return kachel;
    } 
});

L.tileLayer.customTiles = function () 
    {
    var layer = new L.TileLayer.customTiles(); 
    L.setOptions(layer, {maxZoom: 24}); //workaround: L.setOptions overwrite default maxZoom
    return layer; 
    };
var Ausgabekarte = L.tileLayer.customTiles({}).addTo(map);


// Display tile grid borders with leaflet (visual debugging)
// https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149062/display-tile-grid-borders-with-leaflet-visual-debugging
L.GridLayer.GridDebug = L.GridLayer.extend({
    createTile: function (tile_grid) {
        const tile = document.createElement('div');
        tile.style.outline = '1px solid white';
        tile.style.fontWeight = 'normal';
        tile.style.fontSize = '9pt';
            kachelid = tile_grid.z+"/"+tile_grid.x+"/"+tile_grid.y;
            tile_grid_dir = `./gMapCache/z${tile_grid.z + 1}/${Math.floor(tile_grid.x / 1024)}/x${tile_grid.x}/${Math.floor(tile_grid.y / 1024)}/y${tile_grid.y}.jpg`;
        tile.innerHTML = ["<a>" + kachelid + "<br>" + tile_grid_dir + "</a>"];
    return tile;
    },
});
L.gridLayer.gridDebug = function (opts) {return new L.GridLayer.GridDebug(opts);};
map.addLayer(L.gridLayer.gridDebug());

</script>
```